# About a historical note on a famous series

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-history

Currently, I'm doing research on the history of the Basel problem and I happen to notice a small gap. Not on the history of the aforementioned problem per se, since its history is very well documented. In fact, I mean that I wasn't able to determine who was the first person to show the convergence of the series of reciprocals of squares, before its exact value was determined by Leonhard Euler. Although, I did, quite coincidentally I may add, come across a random comment on a post about a proof of the convergence of the series in discussion, saying that Bernoulli (unfortunately, not which member of the Bernoulli family) showed the convergence by bounding the series from above by the number 2. Sadly, it wasn't mentioned whether a Bernoulli brother was the first person to achieve such a result. In case that the previous holds to be true, I kindly ask for anyone to verify such claim. Otherwise, I ask of you to tell/find me that person  and with robust evidence such as sources and web links. You are thanked and muchly appreciated a priori for this endeavour. Have a good day.

Comment: no idea.  note $\frac{1}{4}  + \frac{1}{9}  < \frac{2}{4}, $   next   $\frac{1}{16}  + \frac{1}{25} +\frac{1}{36}  + \frac{1}{49} < \frac{4}{16}, $ then

Comment: @WillJagy I'm sorry this comment isn't helpful at all.

Comment: I think Will's comment shows that the result you're asking about is so easy that it's fair to expect that many people proved it independently and there's no particular name to it.

Comment: @Monchi Are you implying that I should delete this post and forget about it? Plus, how did you deduce that about Will's comment?

Comment: Integral test could help.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I'm aware. Also, that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: To whom it may concern -- downvoting without justification is lazy and not very helpful me think.

Comment: @m-stgt Unfortunately, the downvoters sided with Monchi, agreeing that such question is not worth answering. Sadly, I'll never know the answer nor anyone ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W. Gautschi 2008:

> Stirling, already in 1730, actually calculated the series to nine decimal
> places, but Euler did not yet know this.

[DOI. 10.1137/070702710](https://doi.org/10.1137/070702710)

Comment: That's interesting. Unfortunately, not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Vaskara_GRek_O -- This is an XY-answer, the message is _not_ Stirling and 1730, the important hint is **W. Gautschi**, and the reference list in the linked paper.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In the future, please refrain from making room for ambiguity, since I'm not good at taking hints, that is purely a personal flaw and I apologise for discrediting your answer that quickly.